# GNU Screen equivalent for Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, python, command-line, gnu-screen

Is there such a thing as a terminal multiplexer (i.e. GNU Screen) for the Windows CMD.EXE, or for that matter, is there anything I can use to run a text-only program such as a non-curses python script on Windows XP or Vista in such a way that it can only be detected by using Task Manager, similar programs, or by observing any network traffic that the script generates?

Comment: For python scripts, at least, you can rename *.py to *.pyw to prevent it from opening up a window, perfect for daemons and scheduling things to run, and such.

Comment: Just for your information, the particular python script I am using is supposed to start immediately when the computer starts (in Startup, and as `ATTRIB +R+H`, of course), and it runs constantly until the computer shuts down.

Comment: I do something similar for a scheduler I wrote, *.pyw works perfectly. Have to log to a file, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a *.pyw with a shortcut pointing to it and the required command-line arguments. It now runs just perfectly and with no console window.

Answer (score 5):

More general purpose, you can install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) and enjoy the actual screen tool:

[image]

Comment: That's quite a screenshot -- a version of Firefox back when it was called Phoenix (sometime between Sept. 2001 and April 2003 ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox)). Equally dated Yahoo home page.

Comment: @DougHarris: Nevertheless, a very valid answer.